# Visual studio debug access to external database

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have a question as to how the Visual Studio 2013 debug emulator for Web API works.

I had built a Web API project in Visual Studio 2013 to access a database on an external server. The code was built using VS2013's ASP.NET Web Application project template for a Web API application. Once built, running debug opened a browser window for localhost port 56618, which allowed access from Fiddler to test Http requests.

Once I had the project finished, I published it to a website using Web Deploy to IIS. However, whilst the page would open (now at localhost:9812), an http request would throw an Internal Server Error 500.

Perusing the IIS FailedReqLogFiles, I noticed that the reason that it was failing was that the database server was refusing access to '<Domain>\<machine-name>$'.

I added '<Domain>\<machine-name>$' as a valid login (windows authentication, as the connection string included "Integrated Security=true") on the sql instance with read and write privileges, and the problem was resolved.

The question is, why didn't the Visual Studio debug emulator have the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the emulator was running the website under the context of your own account (e.g. `<Domain>\You`).  Your account had access to the database, so there was no issue.

When you published it to IIS, it started running under the context of a different account (`<Domain>\Machine-Name` - but there are other variants depending on how IIS is configured, and the version of IIS), which didn't have access to your database.